How to connect a USB Android device to a Appium Server in Kubernetes via ADB
I want to connect a USB Android real device to the Appium server which is running in the Container in Kubernetes environment
I deployed the Appium server (Appium 2.0) in Kubernetes and I connected my real Android device to my local machine via ADB.
I want to connect my Android Device to the Appium Server which is running in the Kubernetes


Which node in the cluster is the USB device attached to?  How will you ensure that your Pod will be scheduled on exactly that node, and that it's safe for multiple Pods to be running in normal redeployment scenarios?  Kubernetes might not be the right environment here.

USB device is attached to the local computer.
But my Appium server is running a kubernetes pod
